# How to change JavaFX text color with CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx, text, new-style-class

I write a JavaFX application and I'd like to skin it with css.

I've successfully added a style sheet to my application like this:

```
//Java code
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("/path/to/fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/path/to/css").toExternalForm());
```

I need to change text color, but [there is no](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text) style class for text object by default.

I created FXML files with SceneBuilder. To assign a text object to a class, I typed the class name to the proper text field (Sidebar >> JavaFX CSS >> Style Class).

[image]

CSS file:

```
.myText {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}
```

However if I run my app, this method does change nothing. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That should work. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: did you save in scennebuilder after that ?

Comment: `-fx-text-fill` sets the style of text in a `Label` object, not a `Text` object (which is a shape).  You can set the style of a `Text` object using `-fx-fill`.  For more info, study the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Answer (score 0):

for example here :

```
<Button fx:id="stop" layoutX="100.0"
     layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
     onAction="#onActionStopBtn"
     style=" -fx-background-color:
                    #000000, 
                    linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
                    linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
                    linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);
             -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3;
             -fx-background-radius: 3,2,2,2; 
             -fx-padding: 12 30 12 30;
             -fx-text-fill: white;
             -fx-font-size: 12px;"
     text="Stop" />
```

add some `style` to `FXML` `Button`
see [this](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javafx-css/) for more detail

Answer (score -2):

Finally I figured out what caused the problem. I had to add stylesheet to FXML in SceneBuilder.

After that, everything worked correctly.

---

By the way, I don't know why I had to add stylesheet in SB, despite the fact that I added it in my code earlier. Maybe is it a bug? Or am I just silly?

Comment: don't know why I had to add stylesheet in SB, despite the fact that I added it in my code earlier. Maybe is it a bug?" -> Yes, there is a bug in your code with regard to the stylesheet loaded in your app code, otherwise it would work. I do not know what your bug is.